# game maker part of object collides while other doesn't

Tags: game-maker

When an object collides with a wall, it cannot pass through but some of the sprite can.  When the wall is on the right, the collision works fine but when approaching from another way, part of the object collides.

I have different collision code for different objects, so it's probably not the problem.  The reason for this is that different objects react differently to the collision and they also move differently.

The event for my character that is controlled by the user

```
hor = keyboard_check(ord("D"))-keyboard_check(ord("A"));
ver = keyboard_check(ord("S"))-keyboard_check(ord("W"));
if (place_meeting(x+(hor * sp),y,Object_Wall))
{
    while (!place_meeting(x+sign(hor * sp),y,Object_Wall))
    {
    x += sign(hor);
    }
    hor = 0
}
if (place_meeting(x,y+(ver * sp),Object_Wall))
{
    while (!place_meeting(x,y+sign(ver * sp),Object_Wall))
    {
    y += sign(ver);
    }
    ver = 0
}
x += hor * sp;
y += ver * sp;
```

The code for the enemy which randomly roams around and should walk away after hitting the wall  (Collision with wall event)

```
move_towards_point(random(room_width),random(room_height),sp)
time = random_range(50,150)
```

The problem with the enemy only occurs while he is chasing the player, so now that I think about it, the characters collision is probably the problem.

Any help on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably have a bug when checking the condition of collision, but it is hard to pinpoint your exact problem without seeing the definition of your sprite and your code (post them, please, but make them a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first).
2. Regarding your sentence: "I have different collision code for different objects, so it's probably not the problem." - well, **this is a problem indeed**. Why to have different code for the same task? You are asking for troubles... And that may well be the reason you see the problem now (e.g. the actual collision-checking code in action is not the one you think it is...).